# Efeito de click no Button Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Olá gente tenho a seguinte situação;

bota_selecionado.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#DBDBDB" />
    <corners android:radius="14dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#DBDBDB" />
</shape>
```

botao_normal.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#F2F2F2" />
    <corners android:radius="14dp" />


    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#DBDBDB" />
</shape>
```

botao.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/botao_selecionado" android:state_pressed="true" /> <!-- pressionado -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/botao_selecionado" android:state_focused="true" /> <!-- com foco -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/botao_normal" /> <!-- normal-->
</selector>
```

Coloquei botao.xml como background:

```
android:background="@drawable/botao"
```

Blz testei no meu android 9 pie está ok, quando fui testar no android 4.3 ele nem abriu o projeto: Dis que o projeto parou, o que será isso?

Comment: Já testou no 4.3 sem usar esse efeito? Parece-me que o problema não está nele.

Comment: Testei sim, funcionando perfeitamente sem o efeito.

Comment: Não vejo nada no xml que não seja compatível com o 4.3. Tem de colocar o log de erros na pergunta para que se possa saber qual é o erro.

Comment: Mostrou esse error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.escala1002/com.example.escala1002.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #83: Error inflating class Button

Comment: Consegui resolver, o arquivo xml criado estava como `v24`, então eu copiei seu conteúdo excluir o arquivo e criei novamente, quando criei estava sem o `v24` dps do nome do arquivo, funcionou perfeitamente.